# How to clear a form after submit in Nextjs 13 server side component?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I don't know how to clear form fields after submit in server side component as it cannot use hooks. The submission works ok, but it seems there is not way clear the fields after the call is done. How to solve this here?

I have a Form in this application that submits data to API:

page.tsx:

```
import { Product } from '@/typings'

import Form from './components/Form'

export default async function Home() {

  const res = await fetch('https://64c0eea9fa35860bae9fa770.mockapi.io/products', {
    cache: 'no-cache',
    next: {
      tags: ['products']
    }
  })

  const products: Product[] = await res.json()


  return (
    
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between  text-3xl font-bold">
      <h1 className='mt-2'> Product Warehouse</h1>

      <h2 className='font-bold '>List of Products</h2>

      <div className='flex flex-wrap '>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div
           key={product.id} className='p-5 shadow '>

          <p>{product.product}</p>
          <p>${product.price}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      < Form />

    </main>
  )
}
```

This happens here:

serverActions.ts:

```
"use server"

import { Product } from "@/typings"
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache"

export const addProductToDB = async (e:FormData) => {
    
    const product = e.get("product")?.toString()
    const price = e.get("price")?.toString()

    if (!product || !price) return 

    const newProduct: Product = {
      product: product,
      price: price
    }

    await fetch('https://64c0eea9fa35860bae9fa770.mockapi.io/products', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(newProduct),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      
      
    })
    revalidateTag('products')
    
    
}
```

And this is the form itself:
Form.tsx:

```
"use client"

import { addProductToDB } from "@/actions/serverActions"

function Form() {

  return (
    <form action={addProductToDB} id="myForm" className='flex flex-col gap-5 max-w-xl mx-auto p-5'>
        <input type="text" 
          name='product'
         
          placeholder='Enter Product Name'
          className='border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md'
          
        />
        <input type="text" 
         
        
         name='price'
         placeholder='Enter Price'
         className='border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md'
        />
      
        {/* < AddButton /> */}
        <button type="submit" className='border bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded-md'>
            Add
        </button>
      </form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: As per my knowledge you should be able to add reset button and onclick event in form.tsx as it is a client component

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Because your `Form` is a client component. You can use reference by the hook `useRef` to control your `<form>`. The following is my working example:

```
"use client";

import { actionAddItem } from "@/app/(main)/administration/items/actions";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { experimental_useFormStatus as useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

const ItemForm = () => {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  return (
    <form
      ref={ref}
      className="flex flex-col items-start bg-white rounded-lg p-8 shadow-md"
      action={async (formData) => {
        await actionAddItem(formData);
        ref.current?.reset();
      }}
    >
      <label className="mb-2 text-lg font-semibold" htmlFor="title">
        Title
      </label>
      <input
        className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-lg mb-6 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 w-full"
        type="text"
        name="title"
        id="title"
      />

      <label className="mb-2 text-lg font-semibold" htmlFor="description">
        Description
      </label>
      <input
        className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-lg mb-6 focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200 w-full"
        type="text"
        name="description"
        id="description"
      />

      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded px-4 py-2 hover:bg-blue-600"
        type="submit"
        disabled={pending}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ItemForm;
```

After the form is submmited, just use `ref.current?.reset();` to clear your form.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. How are you triggering the aftersubmit portion of this? Putting some code like `<form onsubmit={ () => ref.current?.reset() } ... ` clears form fields before it gets submitted.

Comment: @Armstrongest It depends on when you would like to clear your form. In most applications, we tend to put it after the form submmited (which is in onsubmit). In my case, because I would like to make sure the resetting is after `actionAddItem`, I put it in the last line in `action`.

Comment: hey great people it worked for me thanks a lot, btw I think the `pending` state should be move outside of the main component, do you agree? thanks

Comment: Not good for UX, form will reset on error and you will need to type again.

Comment: @felipemuner yes you can do that. check https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormStatus for more detail. Just like the example, you can put the `pending` with the submit button together and move it into a separate component.

Comment: @RomkaLTU :D that's true if you would like to a better UX. My response was just addressing the question at hand. However, there are instances where it's necessary to clear form data after an action. This behavior is crucial for maintaining security and usability in certain situations, such as processing online transactions or handling sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is relatively simple if you have a state (in your `actions.ts`) that gives back information that you can listen to.

In my case my form return state looks like this:

```
const initialState: {key: string, message: string}
```

The key can be `success` or `error`. If it's `success` then I use a React `useEffect` hook and React `useRef` to target the form, and reset it:

```
const AddUserForm = () => {
  const formRef = React.useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(addUser, initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef.current && state.key === 'success') {
      formRef.current.reset();
    }
  }, [state.key]);

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} action={formAction}>
      <input type="text" name="user.name" />
      <SubmitButton />
      <p aria-live="polite" className="sr-only" role="status">
        {state?.message}
      </p>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Now, when the submit is successful, the form will reset. If not, the values in the form will remain.

I would recommend splitting up the contents of the form into its own React component, that way you can use `useFormStatus` as follows:

```
const { pending, data, action, method } = useFormStatus();
```

Then you could, for example, disable form elements when the submission is "pending". The `data` is simple `FormData` (JavaScript object) which you can `data.get('user.name')` for purposes such as logging or displaying proper alert messages.

Comment: This works great, thanks!
However, if you try to submit the form for the 2nd time, it will not call the useEffect hook again because `state.key` doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: you can turn your whole form field into a client component, wrap your entire form in a client component and then put that as a child of your page. That way your page is a server component still while the form itself is a client component.
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

Option 2: use react-hook-form package. Example set up here: https://scastiel.dev/server-components-actions-react-nextjs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).